# Convert rows into columns for each distinct id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to convert this

```
tran_id tran_text
1       A
2       B
3       C
1       first
2       second
3       third
1       alpha
2       beta
3       gamma
```

into this

```
tran_id tran_text1 tran_text2 tran_text3
1       A          first      alpha
2       B          second     beta
3       C          third      gamma
```

My ultimate goal is to concat the three values for each tran_id (there are exactly three for each) into a new value, select it, and use it to update another transaction table with the concatenated value.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: We need more information, specifically a third column, to be able to generate the results you want.

Comment: trans_text is not ordered. how do you ensure that A,B,C will fall in trans_text1, first, second,third will fall under trans_text2... do you have some other column to ensure ordering of trans_text ?

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service. Please edit the question to include the SQL you've tried to use and we'll help you fix it to get your desired result.

Comment: `PIVOT` operator is what you are after.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not much of a sql guy so I don't really know where to start or even how to properly google the question.  I looked up some examples of the PIVOT function but they didn't really match exactly what I was looking to do.  Also there is another column that identifies the "type". A, B and C all have type 1, first, second, third all have type 2 etc

Comment: @JohnIngles . . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your desired results suggest an ordering -- without a column that specifies the ordering, your question can't be answered in SQL.

Answer (score 2):

you can handle this using GROUP BY itself.

```
DECLARE @table table(trans_id int, trans_text varchar(50), trans_type int)

insert into @table
values
(1,'A',1),
(2,'B',1),
(3,'C',1),
(1,'first',2),
(2,'second',2),
(3,'third',2),
(1,'alpha',3),
(2,'beta',3),
(3,'gamma',3);

select trans_id,
MAX(CASE WHEN trans_type=1 THEN trans_text ELSE null end) AS trans_text1,
MAX(CASE WHEN trans_type=2 THEN trans_text ELSE null end) AS trans_text2,
MAX(CASE WHEN trans_type=3 THEN trans_text ELSE null end) AS trans_text3
from @table
group by trans_id
```

```
+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| trans_id | trans_text1 | trans_text2 | trans_text3 |
+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|        1 | A           | first       | alpha       |
|        2 | B           | second      | beta        |
|        3 | C           | third       | gamma       |
+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

You can achieve the same result using PIVOT as well.

```sql
select trans_id,[1] as trans_text1, [2] as trans_text2, [3] as trans_text3 
FROM @table
PIVOT (max(trans_text) for trans_type in ([1],[2],[3])) as pvt
```

Comment: This works except for one hitch.  There are more trans_types in the table then just the three, so the result have a lot of null rows.  I tried putting it in a cte and using SELECT *
FROM selction_cte where not(trans_text1 is null) but it's running very slowly.  Is there a way to modify the query itself?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *concatenate* the values, then you would want a single column for the result, not three.  The logic would be:

```
select trans_id, string_agg(trans_text, ',') as trans_texts
from t
group by trans_id;
```

Note that the ordering of `trans_text` is indeterminate.  You can add a `within group (order by)` clause for a stable ordering.

Answer (score 1):

[Click to see tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH2LN.png)

```
    select 
    ID as tran_id,
    REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE([Text]), ',', '.'), 1)) AS tran_text1,
    REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE([Text]), ',', '.'), 2)) AS tran_text12,
    REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE([Text]), ',', '.'), 3)) AS tran_text3
    from 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT ID,
        stuff
        (
            (
                SELECT ','+ [Text] FROM 
                (
    
                select tran_id ID,tran_text as [Text] from meta
    
                ) as tbl_one
    
                WHERE ID = t.ID 
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ),1,1,''
        ) as [Text]
    
        FROM 
    
        (SELECT DISTINCT ID,[Text] FROM 
    
            (
            select tran_id ID,tran_text as [Text] from meta
            ) as tbl_two
        ) t
    ) as tmptbl
```